# Adding Application Insights to Ghost

Tags: azure-application-insights, ghost-blog, ghost

I'm trying to add Application Insights to my Ghost blog running in Azure.
I have read the generic documentation about adding App Insights to a Node.js application, so I know how to do that.

What I have zero idea about is where exactly should I do that for Ghost? I've seen a lot of examples and tutorials out there, but they are all for older versions and I can't use any for the version that I have set up (1.21.3).
No matter where I tried to initialize App Insights, I either got some kind of error or just no data appeared in App Insights.

Can someone point me into the right direction? First step would be to know for sure where to put initialization code. Once I'm sure that the code is at the right place, I might have better chances tracking down the specific error.

Comment: what kind of errors?  the more details we can have the easier we can help

Comment: There were a lot of them - depending on where I put the code, I got a different error. There was one about some misconfigured ACL rules (in a PaaS service? ), there was one abut some mishandled promise failure. I thought that since the errors are so different, first I should figure out where I should put the code for sure and then try to solve that specific error. No point in solving an error with one specific code placement if that turns out to be the wrong place in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overthinking this. 
The solution is to put the initialization code right at the top of the root index.js.

```
var appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup('your_ikey').start();
```

Comment: nit: can you show us *exactly* (without your specific ikey, etc) what you did so that this can help someone else?